# Keybinding code not working

Tags: java, key-bindings

I've been trying to learn how to use Key Binding in Java. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working. When I press 'w' it's supposed to print "Hello!". However pressing 'w' does nothing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Space extends JPanel {


    public static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Space");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Space());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Action wKey = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    };    
    }; 

        InputMap im = frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        ActionMap am = frame.getRootPane().getActionMap();
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("w"),"doSomething");
        am.put("doSomething", wKey);


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });



    }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You are changing the wrong InputMap:

```
//InputMap im = frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
InputMap im = frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

2) You are creating the KeyStroke incorrectly. The string should contain a value found when using KeyEvent_VK?.

So in your case you could use "W", which would map to KeyEvent.VK_W. This will map to keyPressed for "w".

You can also do the binding for keyTyped events:

```
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'),"doSomething"); // or
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("typed w"),"doSomething");
```